# Determine the degree of the splitting field of the polynomial $x^4-2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Determine the degree of the splitting field of the polynomial $f(x) = x^4-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

My attempt: The roots of $f(x)$ are $2^{1/4},-2^{1/4}, 2^{1/4} e^{ \pi i/2} $ and $-2^{1/4} e^{ \pi i/4}.$ The splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4},e^{ \pi i/2}).$ We have that $[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4},e^{ \pi i/2}):\mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4},e^{ \pi i/2}):\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})][\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}): \mathbb{Q}],$ and since $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}) \cong \dfrac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(x^4-2)}$ with $\dim \dfrac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{x^4-2} = \deg x^4-2 = 4.$ Thus $[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}): \mathbb{Q}] = 4.$

How do I determine the degree of $[K= \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4},e^{ \pi i/2}):\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})]$? I'm thinking that the degree of $K = \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4},e^{ \pi i/2})$ over $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})$ is $2$ since every element of $K$ can be expressed as $a = p + qe^{\pi i/2}$ where $p,q \in \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}).$ So the set $\{1,e^{\pi i/2}\}$ is a basis. Thus $[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4},e^{ \pi i/2}):\mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4},e^{ \pi i/2}):\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})][\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}): \mathbb{Q}] = 2 \cdot 4 = 8. $ Is this correct?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776496/show-the-splitting-field-of-polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $e^{2\pi i / 4}=i$ satisfies $i^2=-1$, so that the degree is $\leq 2$ over $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})$. But it equals $2$ since $i \notin \mathbb{R}$, hence $i \notin \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})$.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track and almost there. $[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}):\mathbb{Q}]=4$ since $2^{1/4}$ is a root of the irreducible polynomial $x^4-2$ (by Eisenstein's criterion $p=2$).

At this point we can note that $x^4-2$ still doesn't split in $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})$ since this field is still all real and $x^4-2$ has complex roots. If we adjoin $i=\sqrt{-1}$ then we get all of the remaining roots. $x^2+1$ (the minimal polynomial of $i$ over $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})$ (minimal since $x^2+1$ doesn't factor in $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})$ -- has no roots). Thus $[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4},i):\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})]=2$, so the total degree of your splitting field is $4 \cdot 2=8$.